# HTML and Javascript making a simple addition calculator

Tags: javascript, html, input, addition

I'm trying to make a simple addition calculator. You put two values into the boxes and click the "+" sign and the third box has the sum. However, it looks like everything is right to me but when I click the + sign nothing happens

[image: Here is a picture of my code so far]

Comment: Check the console - your code will be throwing an error because you mistyped (or misremembered) the `getElementById` method. And please post code as code, not as an image (let alone a link to an image).

Comment: 1. There is no `getElementsById` method, because it is not meant to have two elements with the same id. There is only `getElementById`, and it returns one element (not an array). 2. _Please do not post your code as image_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should change `getElementsById()` to `getElementById()` because there is only one id per element.

```html
<input type="text" id="box1"><br/>
<input type="text" id="box2"><br/>
<input type="text" id="+"><br/>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="calcSum()"><br/>

<script>
function calcSum(){
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
let sum = Number(box1) + Number(box2);
document.getElementById("+").value = sum;
}
</script>
```